# Proving complicated convexity example

Tags: convex-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, hessian-matrix

I want to show that $$\textbf{ln}(\sum_{i=1}^ne^{x_i})$$ for $x = (x_1, ..., x_n)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex.
I know that to do this, I can prove that its hessian is positive semidefinite.

I obtain that $$y^THy = \frac{1}
{J}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2e^{x_i} - (\frac{1}{J}\sum_{i=1}^n y_ie^{x_i})^2,$$ where $J = \sum_{j=1}^n e^{x_j}$ and $y_i$ are the entries in the vector $y$ and $H$ is the hessian.

I'm trying to bound the quantity above using Cauchy Schwarz but I haven't been able to do this so far.  Is it possible?  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$J^2y^Thy=\sum_i{(e^{x_i/2})^2}\sum_i{(y_ie^{x_i/2})^2}-\left(\sum_i{y_ie^{x_i/2}e^{x_i/2}}\right)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks so much!